# How does Etherscan compute mining times?

Tags: mining, etherscan, timestamp

Etherscan identifies the miner that mined a block and the corresponding mining time. How does Etherscan compute the mining time?

It seems that the mining time of a block is not the difference between the block timestamp and the parent block timestamp. For example, Etherscan says that block 8988702 was mined in 1 second but its timestamp is 39 seconds greater than the timestamp of block 8988701.

Comment: This appears to be a bug on Etherscan's side. Most blocks have the correct "in x secs", but indeed those two blocks appear to have the wrong entry

Comment: it could be that etherscan dumps this in their DB at the moment a new block at this height pops up. But if it gets re-orged later (i.e. this block should become an uncle) then the timestamp might be wrong. if they dont change their internal timestamps for the block numbers then the times could thus be wrong.